# JQuery fill in of inputs in detached form (hidden filled in but others are not)

Tags: jquery, forms

On my page I have a dummy form like this:

```
<div id="form_container">
  <form id="new_form" action="...">
     <input type="hidden" id="hidden_field" name=...>
     <input type="text" id="text_field" name=...>
     <... submit button ...>
  </form>
</div>
```

The inputs values are initially blank.

I need to recreate this form from time to time on my page with different values in the fields. What I do: first I detach the form container from the DOM and store it in a variable:

```
var dummyForm = $('#form_container').detach();
```

Then, when I need the form popped up I do in some function:

```
var newForm = dummyForm .clone()
$('#hidden_field', newForm).val(dataForHidden);
$('#text_field', newForm).val(dataForText);
```

And then `newForm` is made visible by attaching it to some element on page.

BUT when I inspect the resulting html of the inputs (or I just inspect `newForm.html()` in JS debugger) it looks like this:

```
     <input type="hidden" id="hidden_field" name=... value="xxx">
     <input type="text" id="text_field" name=...>
```

I.e. the value for hidden field was set, but for text field it is lost.

My questions are:
1) Is this a bug, known issue, as-designed feature, or I am doing something wrong?
2) How it can be solved?

I can think of solution to fill in the fields' values when form is already attached to DOM, but in my case this may be a problem as it is being attached to DOM by another library through some chain of callbacks.

**P.S.** I was able to work around this issue by doing `$('#text_field', newForm).attr('value', dataForText);` but still wondering why `val()` works for hidden fields but not for other types.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using attr in jQuery
http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: Thanks, that is what I thought about right now and it works, but still wondering why `val()` works for hidden fields but not for other types.